# How to make array of arrays from a tree datastructure in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, data-structures, tree

[image]

how do i convert the above data structure to

```
[['Tywin'],['Jamie','Cersi', 'Tyrion'], ['Joeffry', 'Myrcella', 'Tomen', 'Lin']]
```

Here's my code:

```js
let Tree = function(name) {
  this.name = name;
  this.children = [];
}

Tree.prototype.addChild = function(parent, name) {
  const node = lannister.contains(parent);
  node.children.push(new Tree(name));
}

var lannister = new Tree('Tywin');

lannister.addChild('Tywin', 'Jamie');
lannister.addChild('Tywin', 'Cersi');
lannister.addChild('Tywin', 'Tyrion');
lannister.addChild('Cersi', 'Joffery');
lannister.addChild('Cersi', 'Myrcella');
lannister.addChild('Cersi', 'Tomen');
lannister.addChild('Tyrion', 'Lin');
bfs();

function bfs(check) {
  //   console.log('traverseBFS called: ', this);
  bfsArray = [];
  var queue = [this];
  var node;
  var tempAr = [];
  bfsArray.push([this.name]);

  while (queue.length > 0) {
    node = queue.shift();
    callback(node.name, node.children.length);
    console.log('current node is: ', node, node.children.length);

    for (var i = 0; i < node.children.length; i++) {
      queue.push(node.children[i]);
      tempAr.push(node.children[i].name);
      if (i === node.children.length - 1) {
        // console.log('The bfs is ', bfsArray, tempAr);
        bfsArray.push(tempAr);
        tempAr = [];
      }
    }
  }

  function callback(itm, length) {

    // console.log('itm is: ', itm);
    if (itm === check) {
      node;
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: Yes I need to find the parent, child, and sibling relation of any given node. Do you have any idea how to do it in javascript?

Comment: line 19 contains the first error: "TypeError: lannister.contains is not a function"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an array and a recursive function which stores the level and pushes the names to the associated level.

```js
function Node(name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.children = [];
}

function Tree(name) {
    this.tree = new Node(name);
}

Tree.prototype.addChild = function (parent, child) {
    function findParent(node) {
        var found;
        if (node.name === parent) return node;
        node.children.some(n => found = findParent(n));
        return found;
    }
    var node = findParent(this.tree) || this.tree;
    node.children.push(new Node(child));
};

Tree.prototype.BST = function () {
    const getNodes = (level = 0) => node => {
        levels[level] = levels[level] || [];
        levels[level].push(node.name);
        node.children.forEach(getNodes(level + 1));
    };

    var levels = [];
    getNodes()(this.tree);
    return levels;
}

var lannister = new Tree('Tywin');

lannister.addChild('Tywin', 'Jamie');
lannister.addChild('Tywin', 'Cersi');
lannister.addChild('Tywin', 'Tyrion');
lannister.addChild('Cersi', 'Joffery');
lannister.addChild('Cersi', 'Myrcella');
lannister.addChild('Cersi', 'Tomen');
lannister.addChild('Tyrion', 'Lin');

console.log(lannister.BST());
console.log(lannister);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: works like a charm...you are a life saver! Thank you very much

Answer (score -3):

A dirty solution: Use an object as a tree structure and keep the character names in the object keys.

```
let family_tree = {
   Jamie: {},
   Cersei: {Joeffry: {}, Myrcella: {}, Tomen: {}},
   Tyrion: {Lin: {}}
}
```

If you need to cycle through the object, use the `Object.keys(family_tree)` method.

Comment: This in no way is a solution.